# Appending two files based on common column

Tags: bash, shell

I understand this question may be repeating, but I don't get exactly what I am looking for. So, here is my necessity. I want to match column-1 between two files and append column-4 of file2.txt to file1.txt. If a column is not matched, I want to append "0" as last field to file1.txt

I have two files taken from NSE site directly.

The data for **file1.txt** looks like:

```
20MICRONS,20170207,41.4,41.75,40.75,40.95,74624
3IINFOTECH,20170207,5.5,5.65,5.5,5.6,2679590
3MINDIA,20170207,11865.7,11919.95,11632.05,11892.25,425
```

and so on. This is my primary file, So all the rows in file1.txt should be retained.

The data for **file2.txt** looks like:

```
20MICRONS,EQ,57597,77.18
3IINFOTECH,EQ,1795693,67.01
```

and so on...

Kindly note, both the file may NOT contain same number of rows.

My **output file** may look like,

```
20MICRONS,20170207,41.4,41.75,40.75,40.95,74624,77.18
3IINFOTECH,20170207,5.5,5.65,5.5,5.6,2679590,67.01
3MINDIA,20170207,11865.7,11919.95,11632.05,11892.25,425,0
```

I tried this,

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print a[$1]","$4}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

but not getting entire row of file1.txt as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (assuming that entries in column-1 occur only once in both files):

```
while read line;
do
   col1=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}'); 
   col4=$(grep $col1 file2.txt | awk -F, '{print $4}');
   echo $line,${col4:=0};
done < file1.txt

20MICRONS,20170207,41.4,41.75,40.75,40.95,74624,77.18
3IINFOTECH,20170207,5.5,5.65,5.5,5.6,2679590,67.01
3MINDIA,20170207,11865.7,11919.95,11632.05,11892.25,425,0
```

Comment: Hi Nehal..Your script works. But its taking too long time as there are around 1700 entries in my file. Any suggestion on better version of script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`join`**:

```
join -a 1 -e 0 -t ',' -j 1 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 2.4' file1 file2
```

If the files aren't sorted to start out with, you'll have to sort them like:

```
join -a1 -e0 -t, -j1 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 2.4' \
    <(sort -k1 -t, file1) \
    <(sort -k1 -t, file2)
```